Убрать ограничение в админке
Доброе.
ocStore 2.3.0.2.3, шаблон Аврора
Обрезается количество символов в поле вопрос от клиент в админке. На сайте я увеличила количество символов. А в админке никак не могу найти ГДЕ это???

